# TextToSpeech show Null Pointer Exception?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, text-to-speech

I am creating one application on TextToSpeech. But when i am trying to run,it throw   exception on following line.

```
tts.speak(ruleOne, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

[Here is my full code for reference](http://pastebin.com/JBvrfqM6)
Please give me any hint. I don't understand  what wrong in my code.  when i    compile my code all value pass correctly but when it jump on above tts object it hit null    pointer exception. is any syntax is wrong? which method call first onCreate() or onActivityResult?
Thanks in Advance

Here is Logcat content.

```
04-10 13:58:34.082: WARN/System.err(19352): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-10 13:58:34.082: WARN/System.err(19352):     at com.example.examguide.ExamRulesActivity.onCreate(ExamRulesActivity.java:60)
04-10 13:58:34.082: WARN/System.err(19352):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-10 13:58:34.092: WARN/System.err(19352):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-10 13:58:34.092: WARN/System.err(19352):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-10 13:58:34.092: WARN/System.err(19352):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-10 13:58:34.092: WARN/System.err(19352):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-10 13:58:34.092: WARN/System.err(19352):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 13:58:34.092: WARN/System.err(19352):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-10 13:58:34.092: WARN/System.err(19352):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-10 13:58:34.102: WARN/System.err(19352):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 13:58:34.102: WARN/System.err(19352):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-10 13:58:34.102: WARN/System.err(19352):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-10 13:58:34.102: WARN/System.err(19352):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-10 13:58:34.102: WARN/System.err(19352):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the full stack-trace.

Comment: @LukasKnuth here i add Logcat

Answer (score 11, accepted):

write

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
```

in your if loop in onCreate () method.

Answer (score 3):

As **Dhruvisha** and **andy boot** suggested, the NullPointerException is obvious because `onCreate` is executed before `onActivityResult`. My suggestion is to bring all your code that use `tts` to a procedure after the check. Here is my suggest code:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle me)
    {
        super.onCreate(me);
        setContentView(R.layout.examrules);
               Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
          checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
          startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);

    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                // success, create the TTS instance
                tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
                this.speak();
            } 
            else {
                // missing data, install it
                Intent installIntent = new Intent();
                installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);

               //tts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.INDIA_HINDI);
                startActivity(installIntent);

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) 
    {        
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) 
        {
            // tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            Locale loc = new Locale ("IN", "en");
            tts.setLanguage(loc);
            Toast.makeText(ExamRulesActivity.this, 
                    "Text-To-Speech engine is initialized", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (status == TextToSpeech.ERROR) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(ExamRulesActivity.this, 
                    "Error occurred while initializing Text-To-Speech engine", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void speak() {
        int isVoiceEnabled=bundle.getInt("isVoiceEnabled");
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);       
        if(isVoiceEnabled==1)
        {
             String ruleOne="hi.";
             String ruleTwo= "How are you"; 
             String ruleThree= "will you meet e=me?"; 
             String ruleFour=  " No,Ok";
                     if (ruleOne!=null && ruleOne.length()>0) 
            {
             tts.speak(ruleOne, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
             tts.speak(ruleTwo, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                 tts.speak(ruleThree, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
             tts.speak(ruleFour, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);

              }       
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Isn't **onCreate** run before **onActivityResult**?

Therefore your tts object will be null. Add extra code to check tts is not null before you call tts.speak

Answer (score 0):

You just need to copy this lines

```
Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
```

**And Write then right after you wrote `setContentView()`**

That Because before doing anything with the `TextToSpeach` object You need to check that data is installed or not.

So the mistake in the code is that you wrote everything of new in that `example` you wrote it before the `intent` call.